# php regex start at the second occurrence of a character?

Tags: php, regex

I've been fighting with this for a while, i have this string :
`storage/12426--the sunflower boys--07-09-2014/Authorization letter/Authorization letter--4--09-15-2015--15-39.pdf`

and I would love to only get this part `07-09-2014` which lies between the first two slashes.

So far I came up with this: `--[^/]*` which only gives me `--the sunflower boys--07-09-2014`.

How do I get what im looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use digits `\d` match:

```
/^[^/]*\/[^/]*(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d)\//
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group within 2 negated character class  :

```
\/[^\/]*(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})[^\/]*\/
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/mL3aF7/1

Answer (score 0):

If the formatting is consistent, you can split on `/` and take the second group, then split on `--` and take the third.

```
$date = explode('--', explode('/', $str)[1])[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use match reset `\K` based regex:

```
--[^-]*--\K[^/]*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE2iZ4/1)